# MYSQL: What is the impact of varchar length on performance when used a primary key?

Tags: mysql, key, varchar

Assuming that you have *no choice* but to use a `varchar` as the primary key of a table in MySQL, is there any advantage to using a shorter `varchar` length for indices, joins, foreign keys?

For example,
VARCHAR(100)
vs
VARCHAR(255)

Comment: I don't see that the provided link has an answer to my question. I understand that using a varchar as a primary key is not ideal as compared to other options. That is not my question. My question is as above - if you have no choice but to use a varchar - is there a value to using a shorter varchar primary key?

Comment: Thanks to Shadow for killing my question before anyone had a chance to reply.